# suggestion for a “strategy game” like platform to test AI algorithm

Tags: graphics-programming, .net, strategy

I wrote a piece of tricky AI algorithms that simulates animals living in an environment and their food seeking, interacting with each other and especially learning new patterns of lifestyle.

now I want to add some graphics to it. so instead of a form with colored dots I would see a 3d environment with different objects moving on it, just like an strategy game.

my code is in VB.net and it uses lots of advanced oop techniques and dynamic nested classes. so changing code to another platform like python, c++ or java is not and option for me. also I am not a trained graphic programmer so which graphic platform I get is what I use as graphic output. If I could only have source of a simple strategy game it would be enough for me.

also any link to opensource .Net strategy games or any source code that can hemlp me in this concept is appreciated.

Comment: You can probably just drop your vb.net dlls in a unity project.

Comment: @Tetrad you are right, but it will make debugging and future developments  really hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Mogre (Managed Ogre), its a Graphics rendering engine (not a game engine), which seems ideal for your situation. Mogre is a .NET binding for Ogre, so it works with C# and VB.NET. There are tutorials for both on the wiki: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE

It is quite simple and fun to use, and should be easy to incorporate into your project.

An alternative is XNA - I know it is mainly used in C#, and im assuming it also works in VB.NET, but im not sure. XNA is a pretty well established game engine, so if you get it working that is also a great choice.

Something else that you might be interested in is a decent physics engine to help your simulation: There are many good ones (check the mogre wiki/forums), but the one I find best and am using currently is BulletSharp (http://code.google.com/p/bulletsharp/)

If you need any help with Mogre/BulletSharp, let me know :)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. XNA 4.0 Refresh works in VB.Net. Also, on a side note I don't think XNA is an engine per-se, though it does set up the game loop and handle most of the basic setup tasks for you (finding the graphics device properties/handles, etc.). Just wanted to clarify if OP doesn't know about it.